# acceder a datos de inputs con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un formulario que se crea a partir de un disparador de eventos (click). Necesito acceder a los valores de los inputs para guardarlos en el localStorage pero no puedo de ninguna manera. A continuación paso el código..

````
``` $('.container-cards').on('click','.btn-search', function(){

    $('#cards-2').prepend(`

              <div id="container-form">
                  <span>Ingrese sus datos y nos comunicaremos a la brevedad</span>
                  <form id="prom-form">
                      <input type="text" id="nombre name="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese su 
                      nombre y apellido">
                      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" 
                      placeholder="ejemplo@email.com">
                      <input id="enviar" class="btn-danger" type="submit" value="enviar">
                  </form>
              </div>
              `)
    $('#cards-2').show()          
}) ```
````

Comment: Para guardarlos en el Local Storage te refieres a guardarlos en la base de datos o en variables ?

Comment: Tienes un error en el id de tu input nombre, te falto cerrar comillas

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código que se supone estás usando para obtener los valores de los `input`?

Comment: @Mateo al parecer esas comillas era lo que me estaba trancando la ejecución. Tendré más precaución la próxima. Gracias por tu tiempo.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno amigo primero que todo, debes cerrar las comillas del id para tu input nombre. Luego para capturar el valor de los inputs con Jquery usas:

```
let nombre = $("#idElemento").val()
```

Para tu caso, si ya tienes los input definidos puedes capturar los valores así(Estoy asumiendo que agregas el div correctamente, solo debes adaptarlo a tu disparador de eventos click). Quedo atento.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>NOTA MEDIA</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div id="container-form">
                    <span>Ingrese sus datos y nos comunicaremos a la brevedad</span>
                    <form id="prom-form" method="POST" action="">
                        <input type="text" id="iptNombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre y apellido">
                        <input type="email" id="iptEmail" name="email" placeholder="ejemplo@email.com">
                        <input id="enviar" class="btn-danger" type="submit" value="enviar">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Requerir BootStrap -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- requerir Sweet Alert -->
        <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
        //Detectar que el documento fue cargado correctamente    
            $(document).ready( ()=>{
                //Detectar que se hizo click en el formulario
                $("#enviar").click( ()=>{
                    //Detener el envio del formulario
                    event.preventDefault()
                    //Capturar valores de los inputs 
                    var name = $("#iptNombre").val()
                    var email = $("#iptEmail").val()
                    //Mostrar en consola los valores 
                    console.log("Nombre: " + name + ", " + "Gmail: " + email)
                })
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```